# What is the completion of a metric space  $(\mathbb{Q}, |\ \ |)$?

Tags: metric-spaces

What is the completion of a metric space $(\mathbb{Q}, |\ \ |)$?

Comment: Do you know why $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete?

Comment: it's $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you just looked this up on Wikipedia you'd find it. If you're having trouble with that definition, feel free to ask about the details.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki : It depends on what "$| \, |$" means. It can be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q_p$, the $p$-adics. It all depends on the chosen metric.

Comment: @david : Perhaps you should precise what "$| \, \, |$" means. If it means the standard absolute value (the geometric distance between two points), then your completion you're looking for is $\mathbb R$, because it can precisely be defined like this. If you want details, as benmachine said, just ask.

Comment: is the usual metric, I have problems to show the isomorphism

Comment: @david : What isomorphism? Between $\mathbb R$ and the completion? Are you thinking about an isomorphism of metric spaces? (i.e. an isometry)

Comment: "a problem to show the isomorphism" ... OK, on one side is the completion of $\mathbb Q$, on the other side is $\mathbb R$ ... so we need a definition of $\mathbb R$ in order to help you.

Answer (score 2):

A metric space $X$ is [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) if every [Cauchy sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) $a_n \in X$  [converges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence) to an element $a \in X$.

The completion of $X$ therefore is the metric space $\bar X$, that contains all elements of $X$, plus the limits of all possible cauchy sequences in $X$ equipped with the same metric as $X$. There is no straight forward way in finding the completion of a Metric space.

In your particular case it was already mentioned in the comments, that the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the canonical metric is $\mathbb{R}$ with the canonical metric.

Comment: help me please in the proof

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a metric space, then the completion of $X$, denote it by $X_c$, is the smallest complete metric space containing $X$ as a subspace. That is, if $Y$ is complete and contains $X$ as a subspace, then $Y$ also contains $X_c$ as a subspace.

If $Y$ is complete, then a subspace of $Y$ is complete if and only if it is closed in $Y$.

Assuming that you have proved these two things, you can use them to find that the completion of $(\mathbb{Q}, |\cdot|)$ is $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$. What must a complete subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ be?

Comment: help me please in the proof